Map Grid Settings in R
Unfortunately, I can't set the grid settings for the map using both mapproj and openainr packages in R. I tried some settings according to the recommendations on the forum, but it didn't affect the result. The issues I'd like to change for the map (I attached .png file):

The number of lines by latitude and longitude. In the code, I set the parameters nx and ny, but it doesn't help.I want the meridians to be spaced every 30 degrees instead of 50 as they are now.
The font size for indicating latitude and longitude on the grid. I used cex and font, but the picture doesn't change.
The size and color of the station symbol - I don't understand which setting to set this with.
I would be very grateful for your help!
My code is below:

trajLevel(traj,
      pollutant = "ch4", 
      year = 2018,
      month = 7,
      statistic = "pscf",
      percentile = 70,
      smooth = TRUE,
      projection ='azequidistant', 
      parameters = NULL,
      orientation=c(90,0,0),
      expand=TRUE,
      col = "increment",
      border = NA,
      map.fill = FALSE,
      xlim=c(-180, 180),
      ylim=c(60,90),
      nx=6,
      ny=3,
      grid.col="grey60",
      grid.text=c(cex = 5, font = 2, col = "red")
      )


